# How to ignore JSON properties in a effective way by remapping Entity into another JsonClass?

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, rest

Recently something has been bugging me surrounding how to customize a **JSON Response.**
So, here's the problem that I'm facing...

This is the entity class.

```
@Table(name="business")

public class Business {

private String var1;
private String var2;
private String var3;
private String var4;
}
```

This is the response class that I will eventually return to the client.

```
public class businessResponse {

private Business business;
}
```

So, if I need only var1 and var2 returned, what should I do. I can `@JsonIgnore` on the **POJO**, but I don't want to do that, as some other response might well need them. I have also tried `@JsonIgnoreProperty({"var3","var4})` on the response class and it didn't work.

Can anyone suggest a solution to achieve this thing? I am new to Hibernate and Spring Boot, so a little help would really work.

Comment: You should make the `businessResponse` class(DTO) completely independent of you `Business` class(Entity), so that your API's don't depend on the DB structure which may evolve in the future.

Comment: Okay, but I was more of looking for a way to extract it from the entity itself, just by making few changes, because it can be tidious to make multiple DTOs for even a single entity.

Comment: That tediousness will be very rewarding in the long end.  If you are lethargic about writing the mapping between the independent dto and entity, you have mapping frameworks to help you in that end

Answer (score 2):

You should use  `@JsonIgnoreProperties` instead of `@JsonIgnoreProperty` on `business` field in `BusinessResponse` instead of `BusinessResponse` class

```
public class BusinessResponse {

   @JsonIgnoreProperties({"var3", "var4" })
   private Business business;
}
```

Comment: @BabulAkhtar In your spare time try to read here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: That's a good answer, although hardcoding property names is not the best